# Can't find \ lost auto start configuration, where could it be?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, debian-wheezy

I did something to make 'Screen' run ever time I start a terminal to my raspberry pi (set up as a headless server). but now I keep leaving sessions dangling and want to remove the startup command..

But I cant remember where it is.

There is nothing in `/etc/rc.local`, there is no `init.d` script, can't find it in `/etc/profile.d`

when I run `ls/etc/rc*.d` there are no references with 'Screen' or any script with a name I'd remember adding

Where else should I look ?  I can't see any thing in my home dirs using `ls -a` Where else could I have configured a program to auto-start when I log on ?

Comment: Try `grep -i screen /etc/* /etc/*/* /etc/*/*/* /home/*/.* /home/*/.*/* /home/*/.*/*/*`: one of those directories should contain a file referring to your program.

Comment: @AFH Found it in /etc/profile,  thank you kindly... can you make an answer of this so I can accept it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of places where your start-up command may be set. The following command should check most of them:

```
grep -i screen /etc/* /etc/*/* /etc/*/*/* /home/*/.* /home/*/.*/* /home/*/.*/*/*
```

One of those directories should contain a file referring to your program.